# Querying in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have data like this

```
+----+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+----------------+------------+-------+
| id | seq | allocation | template_id | headcount_id | cost_center_id | country_id | total |
+----+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+----------------+------------+-------+
|  1 |   1 |       1.00 |           1 |            1 |           1234 |          1 |    10 |
|  2 |   1 |       1.00 |           1 |            1 |           1234 |          1 |    12 |
|  3 |   1 |       1.00 |           1 |            1 |           1234 |          1 |     5 |
|  4 |   1 |       1.00 |           1 |            1 |           1234 |          1 |     8 |
|  5 |   1 |       1.00 |           1 |            1 |           1234 |          1 |     4 |
|  6 |   1 |       1.00 |           1 |            1 |           1234 |          1 |    12 |
|  7 |   1 |       1.00 |           1 |            1 |           1234 |          1 |     2 |
|  8 |   1 |       1.00 |           1 |            1 |           1234 |          1 |    13 |
|  9 |   2 |       0.50 |           1 |            2 |           6578 |          2 |    41 |
| 10 |   2 |       0.50 |           1 |            2 |           6578 |          2 |    13 |
| 11 |   2 |       0.50 |           1 |            2 |           6578 |          2 |   200 |
| 12 |   2 |       0.50 |           1 |            2 |           6578 |          2 |    14 |
| 13 |   2 |       0.50 |           1 |            2 |           6578 |          2 |   478 |
| 14 |   2 |       0.50 |           1 |            2 |           6578 |          2 |   658 |
| 15 |   2 |       0.50 |           1 |            2 |           6578 |          2 |   589 |
+----+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+----------------+------------+-------+
```

Image: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0S30z.png)

I need to get the total of total by country and sum of allocation distinct by seq.

Output would be like

```
+------------+------------+-------+
| allocation | country_id | total |
+------------+------------+-------+
|          1 |          1 |     66|
|       0.50 |          2 |   1993|
+------------+------------+-------+
```

Comment: Annual DC is the Total of Total.

Comment: Annual is the SUM of TOTAL by countries

Comment: Is that a single input table?  You seem to have 6 columns that are correlated to each other.

Comment: I think that @DxTx (+1) gave you a great answer. There are a few articles about how to ask questions here on my profile - you might want to take a look? You appear to be shifting the goalposts in terms of your desired answer - what more could DxTx have done? p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this..?

Table structure and sample data

```
CREATE TABLE sample (
  id int, 
  seq int, 
  allocation FLOAT(10, 2), 
  template_id int, 
  headcount_id int, 
  cost_center_id int, 
  country_id int, 
  total int
);
INSERT INTO sample 
VALUES 
  (1, 1, '1.00', 1, 1, 1234, 1, 10), 
  (2, 1, '1.00', 1, 1, 1234, 1, 12), 
  (3, 1, '1.00', 1, 1, 1234, 1, 5), 
  (4, 1, '1.00', 1, 1, 1234, 1, 8), 
  (5, 1, '1.00', 1, 1, 1234, 1, 4), 
  (6, 1, '1.00', 1, 1, 1234, 1, 12), 
  (7, 1, '1.00', 1, 1, 1234, 1, 2), 
  (8, 1, '1.00', 1, 1, 1234, 1, 13), 
  (9, 2, '0.50', 1, 2, 6578, 2, 41), 
  (10, 2, '0.50', 1, 2, 6578, 2, 13), 
  (11, 2, '0.50', 1, 2, 6578, 2, 200), 
  (12, 2, '0.50', 1, 2, 6578, 2, 14), 
  (13, 2, '0.50', 1, 2, 6578, 2, 478), 
  (14, 2, '0.50', 1, 2, 6578, 2, 658), 
  (15, 2, '0.50', 1, 2, 6578, 2, 589);
```

Query

```sql
SELECT 
  Max(allocation) as allocation, 
  country_id, 
  Sum(total) as total 
FROM 
  sample 
GROUP BY 
  country_id
```

Output

```
+-------------+-------------+-------+
| allocation  | country_id  | total |
+-------------+-------------+-------+
|          1  |          1  |    66 |
|        0.5  |          2  |  1993 |
+-------------+-------------+-------+
```

Online Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/547260/3/0

Comment: The end result should be group by countries while getting the sum of totals by countries and sum of allocation with distinct seq by countries.

Comment: it works, but it does not add up the allocation where the seq should be distinct.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08ce954/1

Comment: i need the allocation added to other row with the same country id

Comment: @JuliusYerro EACH allocation in your sample mathes THE SAME country id. So your phrase makes no sense.

Comment: @Akina but they have different SEQ. The output should be Total Allocation from Distinct Seq, GroupBy Country ID, SUM Total

Comment: @JuliusYerro I'm sorry. I don't understand the question. Maybe somebody else will be able to help you. However, you may want to add clear sample data and a clear output from that sample data that will highlight what you need.

Comment: i need to get the sum of total by countries and total of allocation distinct by seq which should be grouped by countries